# Alert me if my mic input reaches a certain level

Tags: applescript

My housemate complains that I speak too loud (when having phone calls or during Zoom meetings). After failing to consciously control my voice level many times, I decided to ask for help by making this post. I would like to create an automated script (e.g. apple script & Automator) to alert/notify me if my mic input reaches a certain voice level.

I tried using those audio editor apps like Voicemeeter or Audacity. They have a sound level indicator that will turn red when the sound reaches a certain level. However, I cannot constantly monitor those apps during phone calls/meetings. It will be very helpful for me to receive a ping/alert.

I oftentimes wear a headphone for phone calls/meetings, so you can safely assume the mic is always on when the detection is needed.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  Is your hearing OK?

Comment: My hearing is ok. I just tend to get excited easily during conversations...